# How to remove duplicate lists that contain elements in different order?

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7, duplicates

Suppose I have the list [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,2,1]], the first and last element (which are also lists) of the list are actually the same - they contain the same set of numbers, just with different order. If I want to create a function that takes in a list of list, and remove those duplicate list elements (in this case, remove either [1,2,3] or [3,2,1] and keep the remaining one), how do I do that?

thank you

Comment: First, sort your list of list, and then remove the duplicates.

Comment: Check with array_intersect function..it will help you

Comment: Does order need to be preserved

Comment: I have just checked the depth first search and it seems that I've solved my problems. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `set` and a `frozenset`.

Sets store only unique items and they are unordered.

```
>>> {3, 1, 2} == {2, 1, 3}
True
```

But they can only store immutable items, so that's why we will also need a `frozenset`.

```
>>> {set([1, 2, 3])}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-16-ddc0311520e7>", line 1, in <module>
    {set([1, 2, 3])}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

>>> {frozenset([1, 2, 3])}
set([frozenset([1, 2, 3])])
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,2,1]]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in lst if frozenset(x) not in seen and not seen.add(frozenset(x))]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Nice answer I was thinking of this frozenset solution

Answer (score 3):

Convert each and every element of the list to a set and then to a tuple and form a new set to get the result you expect.

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,2,1]]
print(set(tuple(set(item)) for item in data))
# {(4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3)}
```

We can use `frozenset` here, like this

```
print(set(frozenset(item) for item in data))
# {frozenset({1, 2, 3}), frozenset({4, 5, 6})}
```

Comment: If order doesnt matter then I would definitely go with this solution but OP hasnt stated

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is using map:

```
map(list, set(map(frozenset, lst)))
```

This will give you [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

What it basically does, is it applies frozenset to the lst. We use frozenset because set only stores immutable items. 
Doing map(frozenset, lst), gives us:
    [frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([4, 5, 6]), frozenset([1, 2, 3])]
From that, apply set and we get:
    set([frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([4, 5, 6])])

and mapping list to this gives us [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]